# Bootstrap modal dialog, show.bs.modal event relatedTarget is undefined. How can I get clicked element?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, events, dialog, modal-dialog, fuelux

Button invoked modal dialog:  When button is clicked, event is fired the resulting event reference e.relatedTarget is undefined.  So, how can I get the invoking button from the handler? e does not seem to contain any reference to the invoking button.

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  console.log(e.relatedTarget) // do something...
})
```

Reference: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: This seems to be an issue with Bootstrap v3.2.0 and not an issue with some later versions (v3.1.1).

Comment: @wes.hysell Is there an issue report on the BS 3.2.2 GitHub page about this issue somewhere?

Comment: try this answers, it work for me:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/26187487/3067077

Answer (score 26):

Thanks Geo1004.. I was already using JS to trigger the "show" event on the modal, but I was missing the second argument. So the event.relatedTarget was undefined.

If anyone else is going the JS route (instead of using data attributes) I would make sure you are sending the button as a jQuery object -

```
$( "#myModal" ).modal( "show", $( "#buttonBeingClicked" ) );
```

Comment: oowww save my life!! tks

Comment: This works for me with Bootstrap 3.3.5 and jQuery 2.x.

Comment: How do you use it with **`.modal({show:true,});`** ?

Comment: I believe show: true is implied. true to open the modal and false to close it. Are you looking to pass it additional options?

Answer (score 22):

Take a look at the following [Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/yPkQNLIqeI).

When run the show event seems to include a proper reference to `e.relatedTarget`.

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var button = e.relatedTarget;
    if (button != null)
    {
        alert("Launch Button ID='" + button.id + "'");
    }
})
```

Take a look at the [Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/yPkQNLIqeI) to see if your own code deviates from it. (I copied the original Bootstrap sample code snippet directly from the [link](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) that you provided.)

I hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: you must have taken your bootply example away because I can't find it.

Comment: The link (http://www.bootply.com/yPkQNLIqeI) still appears to work. Be sure to press the "Launch demo modal" button in order to run the demo code.

Comment: Is the example at [link](http://www.bootply.com/yPkQNLIqeI) working as intended for question purpose? I mean that I never get the message from the alert related with e.relatedTarget. That object seems to be always NULL.

Answer (score 10):

This is a workaround. You can open the modal with JS instead and relatedTarget will be set. 
You should not miss to pass the button as a second parameter for the 'modal' method.

You will be able to pass data references (here address-target)

```js
$('.listing_btn').on 'click', ->
  $('.modal').modal('show', $(@))

$('#modal').on 'show.bs.modal', (event)->
   button = $(event.relatedTarget)
   address_id = button.data('address-target')
   console.log address_id
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and wasted the whole evening to fix it.
My bootstrap.js version was simply to old and the $(event.relatedTarget) was not available for the 'show.bs.modal' event.
Anyone with the same problem should check his bootstrap version first.
Then simply stick to the official site example :
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target
You'll find your reference in $(event.relatedTarget).

Comment: Updated from 3.3.5 to 3.3.7 ... didn't work, am using `.load()` to get modal data.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
   console.log($(e.relatedTarget)); // You will get the element you want! Cheers
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myModal').modal('show',$('#myButton'))

$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal',function(e){
   console.log($(e.relatedTarget))
})
```