# Bootstrap modal relatedTarget is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to get the clicked element using the property `relatedTarget` of the   `show.bs.modal` event. It's always getting undefined though.

This is what I have:

```
  $("#curCarSelect").on('click', function(e) {
    $("#curCarModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
      modalOpenedby = event.relatedTarget; 
      alert(modalOpenedby);
    }).modal('toggle');
  });
```

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 49, accepted):

try:

```
$("#curCarSelect").on('click', function(e) {
   $modal.modal('toggle', $(this));
});
```

where $modal is your modal element to open, then:

```
$modal.on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
   var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
})
```

Comment: This should be the accepted best answer. The currently "best" one is useless.

Comment: Undefined elements when accessing the event object

Comment: This should be in bootstraps documentation.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to use `event.relatedTarget` in you dynamically opened modal then you can pass the target as a second argument in the modal function.

```
$("#curCarSelect").on('click', function(e) {
    $("#curCarModal").modal('toggle', $("#curCarSelect")); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[Per the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage):

> **If caused by a click**, the clicked element is available as the `relatedTarget` property of the event.

But you're just calling `.modal('toggle')`. **That doesn't involve any click event**, hence why `relatedTarget` in undefined in your case.

Comment: Can you post code that **does** involve the click event, so that `relatedTarget` is **not** undefined? I am trying to learn this really bad and a working example on grounds of BS 3.2.2 would be ace! Thank you ;)

Comment: It will be defined when you use `data-toggle="modal"`

Comment: @lowtechsun, you able to figure this out?

Comment: @user1149244 I have moved away from bootstrap a long long time ago and quite possibly won't ever touch that. Look into [Susy](http://susy.oddbird.net/) or [Ant](https://github.com/corysimmons/postcss-ant) if you will, just a suggestion. For a solution check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30082273/1010918), it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I make it worked for me. Try this:

```
$("#curCarSelect").on('click', function(e) {
    $("#curCarModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
        modalOpenedby = event.relatedTarget; 
        alert(modalOpenedby);
    }).modal('toggle', e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for this worked for me on bootstrap 2:

```
$("a[data-toggle='modal']").on('click', function(e) {
    $_clObj = $(this); //clicked object
    $_mdlObj = $_clObj.attr('data-target'); //modal element id 
    $($_mdlObj).on('shown.bs.modal',{ _clObj: $_clObj }, function (event) {
           $_clObj = event.data._clObj; //$_clObj is the clicked element !!!
           //do your stuff here...
    });
});
```

Answer (score -3):

try this:

```
$('#curCarModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    modalOpenedby = event.relatedTarget; 
});

$("#curCarSelect").on('click', function(e) {
    $("#curCarModal").modal('toggle'); 
    alert(modalOpenedby);
});
```

Comment: event is automatically passed in chrome browser this might fail in browsers where the event is not automatically passed like in Firefox.