# JQuery Modal Trigger for Unique Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Let's say I have a collection containing 3 elements.

Each element has a corresponding remove button that I would like to initiate a POST to my server. Right now I have it setup so that when "Remove" button is pressed, a confirmation modal pops up with "yes" and "no" buttons. I am using the same modal for each element.

Problem is, when I click "yes" in modal, how can I have it *know* which remove button I clicked that launched the modal?

Here is a link to a gist containing the problematic code
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/85481507a1171467cae5

I have tried using a suggestion below that implements the following:

```
$('#hingle_dingle_0').on('click', function(e){
    $('#confirmRemoveNetwork').modal('toggle', $(this));
});
$('#confirmRemoveNetwork').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
    console.log(button);
});
```

However this returns an empty set. I can't for goodness sake figure out why it doesn't find the event.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please show how you are triggering the modal.

Comment: @Malk added a fiddle to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

The modal is autoposting because you are opening it with a `<button>` inside a form with an input. Unless you tell it not to, this will cause a form submit. Simply set the type to button (instead of submit which is default): `<button type="button">`

You can capture the calling button by tapping into the event thrown when the modal is opened:

```
$('#confirmRemoveNetwork').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log(e.relatedTarget.id);
});
```

Finally, be sure your IDs are unique. You cannot have both "remove network" buttons using the same id of `removenetworkbtn`.

Comment: Will try this when I get home and post results, thank you for promptness.

Comment: Saw the button inside the form right after posting, thanks for clarifying on that. As for `e.relatedTarget.id`, this didn't work. I fixed the ids (#remove_btn1) so they're all unique, however when doing console.log(e) on your function above, I found no relatedTarget nor anything that gives me the relationship.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187370/bootstrap-modal-relatedtarget-is-undefined

Comment: I see that. Implemented on my own sheet, I get `[Log] Object (networks, line 187)
currentTarget: div#confirmRemoveNetwork.modal fade in
data: undefined
delegateTarget: body.modal-open
handleObj: Object
isTrigger: 3
jQuery21408603978690225631: true
namespace: "bs.modal"
namespace_re: /(^|\.)bs\.(?:.*\.|)modal(\.|$)/
result: undefined
target: div#confirmRemoveNetwork.modal fade in
timeStamp: 1446152046437
type: "shown"
__proto__: Object
` back for e. Here is a link to the source. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4e771aeb3c568d3a6a41

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but try including the bootstrap.js before the script tag.